# How to manage software that isn't in the App Store?

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, mac-appstore

I'm a Linux sysadmin. I naturally try to apply Linux-y solutions to Mac problems. One problem I'm currently having is managing software on end-user laptops at scale, when the software I want to add is not available in the App store.

Which seems to be most/all of the software I need to manage or install.

- Browsers: Firefox, Chrome, etc. Not in App store
- VPN clients: Tunnelblick, Viscosity
- Internally managed Antivirus software

etc.

What is the "Apple Way" to manage software across an organization when that software is not available in the App Store?

Comment: Haven't used it myself so not going to post this as an answer as I can't provide specifics, but it looks like [Apple Remote Desktop](https://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/) is their official solution...

Comment: ARD can do this and there are also commercial, 3rd party, applications that can manage Macs in an enterprise and do what you need.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding something, ot maybe I'm just asking the wrong question. I don't think I want a "remote desktop" solution, unless ARD does something above and beyond just logging in to mac computers remotely. I want a way to image, re-image, install, and provision laptops, as well as remote install and similar. Without having to log on to a desktop.